# to insert new element based on another element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath-2.0

I have a input xml file like this

```
<document startnum="1" language="en-US">
<meta>
<categories>
<category medicalbranch="surgery">
</category>
</categories>
<doctitle>Traumatology for the Physical Therapist</doctitle>
<relatedobjects>
<relpdfio/>
</relatedobjects>
<publisher>
<publishername>Georg Thieme Verlag</publishername>
<copyright>Georg Thieme Verlag</copyright>
</publisher>
</meta>
```

The output xml should be like below

```
<document startnum="1" language="en-US">
<meta>
<categories>
<category medicalbranch="surgery">
</category>
</categories>
<isbn type="print"> </isbn>
<isbn type="online"> </isbn>
<materialid/>
<metadata type="searchlevel"/>
<doctitle>Traumatology for the Physical Therapist</doctitle>
<relatedobjects>
<relpdfio/>
</relatedobjects>
<publisher>
<publishername>Georg Thieme Verlag</publishername>
<copyright>Georg Thieme Verlag</copyright>
</publisher>
</meta>
```

I need to insert above mentioned 4 elements whenever "meta" element does not contain "isbn" in source.

I have written xslt like below:

```
<xsl:template match="meta">
    <xsl:if test="node[not(isbn)]">
        <xsl:element name="isbn">
            <xsl:attribute name="type">print</xsl:attribute> 
            <xsl:text>&#xA0;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:element><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:element name="isbn">
            <xsl:attribute name="type">online</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:text>&#xA0;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>        
        <xsl:element name="materialid"></xsl:element><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:element name="metadata">
            <xsl:attribute name="type">searchlevel</xsl:attribute></xsl:element>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <!--<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">-\-&gt;</xsl:text>-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Could you please help us to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and then decide where you want to insert the new elements, for instance after the `categories` element e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="meta[not(isbn)]/categories">
  <xsl:next-match/><!-- copies the categories element with the identity transformation template -->
  <isbn type="print"> </isbn>
  <isbn type="online"> </isbn>
  <materialid/>
  <metadata type="searchlevel"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Martin. It's working in my file.

Comment: I want to keep self closing tags like, <materialid></materialid>
<metadata type="searchlevel"></metadata>. Can u help me that how to write code for it.

Comment: XSLT does not define whether an empty element is serialized as e.g. `<foo/>` or `<foo></foo>` so I am afraid that is a task outside of XSLT. At http://xsltransform.net/3MvmrAL your example input seems to be transformed fine with the `<materialid/><metadata type="searchlevel"/>` result but in general that depends on the XSLT processor/serializer.

Comment: Thank you for your response Martin. I got more idea about XSLT processor.